# Setting LocalStorage store for nested list

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I've created a localstorage store, and stored demo values in it following this tutorial:

http://sureshdotariya.blogspot.com/2013/03/understanding-local-storage-proxy-in.html

And it all works fine, I've viewed the store data in the resources in chrome and it is there, and when I load the page it loads fine, no errors, but it shows no data, here's my view code:

```
Ext.define('MyTest.view.SearchPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'searchpanel',
    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'nestedlist',
            title: 'Search Results',
            displayField: 'Name',
            store: {     
                storeId: 'UserStore',
                fields: ['Name']
            },
        }]
    }
});
```

What am I missing here? Can I use local storage store as the store for the nested list? And if yes then why it shows "No items found", I've added the store in app.js, I tried requiring it in this view but that did not work.

Your help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where do you put data in the store? I see that you define a new store here, but not that you put any data into it. If you have a store with data in it, I would guess that you have two stores - one with data, and one bound to the view. Please check whether `Ext.ComponentQuery.query("nestedlist")[0].getStore()` contains data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ext.dataview.NestedList](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList) requires [Ext.data.TreeStore](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore) instead of [Ext.data.Store](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) ( in the sample URL you gave ).

There are `root`, `defaultRootProperty` config required in [Ext.data.TreeStore](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore), and `leaf` property in items.

Of course you can set [Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage) as proxy in [Ext.data.TreeStore](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore) , try with these codes :

```
Ext.define('ListApp.model.User', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     config: {
         fields: [{
             name: 'text',
             type: 'string'
         }]
     }
 });
Ext.define('App.store.User', {
    config: {
        model: 'ListApp.model.User',
        defaultRootProperty: 'items',
        root: data
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'UserInfo'
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: I ended up changing nestedlist to list, as I don't absolutely need to load nested data, I did not know nestedlist requires TreeStore, thank you! I guess I'll have to cross that bridge when I get to it